# How to add comment to post on this same site?

Tags: django

i created blog and possibility to comment every post. But now i have it on two different sites. On page with post i have link to my comment form and there i create comment. Is that possible to add form to this post site?

So i would like to have post_detail, form to add new comment and comments on one this same site. Now i have only post and comments.

views.py:

```
def comment_new(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect(post_detail, pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'form': form})
```

template:
post_detail.html (part with comment stuff):

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_new' pk=post.pk %}">Add comment</a>

{% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    {{ comment.created_date }}
    <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
    {{ comment.text }}
{% endfor %}
```

comment_new.html

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comment/$', views.comment_new, name='comment_new'),
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(unique=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=256)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1028)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Post your models.py please

Comment: Thanks, i added in first post.